# HttpClient's authorization headers returning null, tried all method from research but both of them not working

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, authhttp

I have a fake back end service which provided by the tutorial, but the angular version of the tutorial is quite old. I decided to use new version of angular and auth0/jwt, but it's totally different from what the tutorial are teaching. I can't solve the problem of authorization headers are returning null even though I have JwtModule.forRoot in the app.module

I tried to do `console.log(connection.request.headers.get('Authorization'));` but it's returning null

here is my code:
order.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class OrderService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getOrders() {
    return this.http.get('/api/orders');
  }
}
```

fake-backend.ts

```
import { Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export function fakeBackendFactory(
    backend: MockBackend, 
    options: BaseRequestOptions) {

  let token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6Ik1vc2ggSGFtZWRhbmkiLCJhZG1pbiI6dHJ1ZSwiZXhwIjoxMTExMTExMTExMX0.MkMCCNb5PMF-vdgpJTH0ZxFXeSPn0lJGyNBWkIJDzqE';

  backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
    // We are using the setTimeout() function to simulate an 
    // asynchronous call to the server that takes 1 second. 
    setTimeout(() => {
 // 
       // Fake implementation of /api/orders
       //
       if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/api/orders') && 
           connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Get) {
         if (connection.request.headers.get('Authorization') === 'Bearer ' + token) {
            connection.mockRespond(new Response(
              new ResponseOptions({ status: 200, body: [1, 2, 3] })
          ));
          } else {
           connection.mockRespond(new Response(
             new ResponseOptions({ status: 401 })
           ));
          }
        }



    }, 1000);
  });

  return new Http(backend, options);
}

export let fakeBackendProvider = {
    provide: HttpClient,
    useFactory: fakeBackendFactory,
    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
};
```

app.module.ts

```
import { OrderService } from './services/order.service';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { fakeBackendProvider } from './helpers/fake-backend';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, Http, BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { JwtModule, JWT_OPTIONS } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; 

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { NoAccessComponent } from './no-access/no-access.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import { AdminAuthGuard } from './services/admin-auth-guard.service';

export function tokenGetter(){
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    NoAccessComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent, 
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard]
      },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'no-access', component: NoAccessComponent }
    ]),
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: { tokenGetter,
      whitelistedDomains: ['http://localhost:4200'],
      blacklistedRoutes: [],
      headerName: 'Authorization',
      throwNoTokenError: true,
      skipWhenExpired: false,
      authScheme: 'Bearer '
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    OrderService,

    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    AdminAuthGuard,

    // For creating a mock back-end. You don't need these in a real app. 
    fakeBackendProvider,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

admin.component.ts

```
import { OrderService } from './../services/order.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  orders: any[];

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orderService.getOrders()
      .subscribe(orders => this.orders = <any[]>orders);
  }
}
```

the `connection.request.headers.get('Authorization')` is actually returning null, so how can I really change the authorization headers into `'Bearer ' + token` ? I have work with this for 2 days..... it's still not solving I just want to implement something like AuthHttp

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the header in your service like this

```
getOrders() {
 const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};

 return this.http.get('/api/orders', httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: but this is way longer, if using AuthHttp I can even just write `return this.http.get('/api/orders', httpOptions);` in the `getOrders()` function then other things it will be automatically done

Comment: this is best practise suggest by angular team. To prevent rewritten header everytime I suggest you create common http service with Authorization header to use everywhere

Comment: ...but it's still not working too, it still not passing the authorization part

Comment: @gamesymbol you have to use HttpClientModule not HttpClient

Comment: Why you HttpClientModule and HttpClient  in your module ? Import only HttpClientModule

Comment: it still the same... actually I'm not using the HttpClient anywhere because it was dark blue colour. is that possible because of the fakebackend are returning a Http? `return new Http(backend, options);`